# Estimate or bound the float conversion error in Python

Tags: python, numpy, types

I am reading data from a csv file that contain numbers, and convert them to numpy float32 / float64.

I'd like to get an estimation (or a bound) of the error that I have when converting. Ideally I'd like to get a function that would tell me for a number n in my file what error I have commited. I understand that it might not be easy because the number need to be read in a type with perfect precision. I havent found a numpy type that would allow for that. So I started with a simpler problem and I am now trying to estimate the error from a number declared in Python.

I am starting with the code below :

```
import numpy as np

n = 71238457.2500001

print(n-np.float64(n))
print(n-np.float32(n))
print(np.float64(n)-np.float32(n))
```

However, when declaring my number n in Python I think it automatically builds a float64. So I end up with no error for float64 conversion and the same result for the last two operations (conversion to float 32, conversion from float64 to float32) :

```
0.0
1.2500001043081284
1.2500001043081284
```

For a given number, what would be a function to get, estimate or bound the error of float32 / float64 conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your numbers are not too large and the difference in the representations exists only in the decimal parts, not in the integer parts.

Python's integer numbers are exact. Consider calculating the decimal part of the difference using integer numbers. Python prints up to 26 decimal digits:

```
n = '71238457.2500001'

n_orig = int(n.split(".")[1].ljust(26, "0"))
n_fl32 = int("{:.26f}".format(np.float32(n)).split(".")[1])
n_fl64 = int("{:.26f}".format(np.float64(n)).split(".")[1])

print(f"{n_fl64-n_fl32:026}e-26")
#25000010430812835693359375e-26
print(f"{n_fl64-n_orig:026}e-26")
#00000000430812835693359375e-26
print(f"{n_orig-n_fl32:026}e-26")
#25000010000000000000000000e-26
```

Comment: My end goal is to check that the error isn't too big. So assuming the error doesn't get to the integer part - or in other words assuming it is bounded by 1 - kind of defeat the purpose of the question... However, your answer and the idea to work on both integer and decimal parts separately seems to be a good start of an answer. I'll try to work something out and accept your answer if it doesn't get ugly.

Comment: You can easily extend the solution to cover the integer part. Simply include as much of it as you want into the newly constructed integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Following @DYZ answer, it is not too difficult to get the integer part separately:

```
n = '71238457.2500001'

n_orig_int = int(n.split(".")[0])
n_orig_dec = int(n.split(".")[1].ljust(26, "0"))
n_fl32_int = int("{:.26f}".format(np.float32(n)).split(".")[0])
n_fl32_dec = int("{:.26f}".format(np.float32(n)).split(".")[1])
n_fl64_int = int("{:.26f}".format(np.float64(n)).split(".")[0])
n_fl64_dec = int("{:.26f}".format(np.float64(n)).split(".")[1])

print(n_orig_int-n_fl64_int)
print(n_orig_int-n_fl32_int)
print(n_fl64_int-n_fl32_int)

print(f"{n_orig_dec-n_fl64_dec:026}e-26")
print(f"{n_orig_dec-n_fl32_dec:026}e-26")
print(f"{n_fl64_dec-n_fl32_dec:026}e-26")
```

Will give :

```
0
1
1
-0000000430812835693359375e-26
25000010000000000000000000e-26
25000010430812835693359375e-26
```

After that it get a bit ugly if you want to combine both part into one output due to the signs.

Comment: Easy. Simply multiply the integer part by 1e26 and add it to the decimal [art.

Answer (score -1):

Assign to a variable and then subtract them to see difference

```
x= np.float64(n)
y = np.float32(n)
print(x-y)
```